# Выбор из select в sql

Tags: yii2

Добавляю такой select во вью

```
<select name="list">
    <option value="mouse">mouse</option>
    <option value="keyboard">keyboard</option>
    <option value="headphones">headphones</option>
</select>
```

В модели создал

```
$list = Yii::$app->request->post('list', 'mouse')

$result =  Yii::$app->getDb()->createCommand('
        Select *
         from order_table
         where items_sort in :list
    ')->bindValue(':list', '('.$list.')')
    ->queryAll();

    return $result;
}
```

Контроллер выглядит так

```
 public function actionIndex()
    {
        $data = null;
        if(isset($_GET['last_month'])) {

            $data = order::getTest();
        }
        $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $data,
            'sort' => [
            ],
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 50,
            ],
        ]);

        return $this->render('index',['dataProvider' =>$dataProvider]);

    }
```

Но при выборе любого значения в запрос подставляется значение по умолчанию. В чем может быть проблема?
Код формы

```
<div style="width: 25%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;"><br>
        <?php $form1 = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'last_month', 'method' => 'GET']); ?>
        <input type="hidden" value="0" name="last_month">

        <div class="form-group" style="float:left;margin-left: 5px;">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Прошлый <br> месяц', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'n1',
                'style'=>"width:120px;display:inline-block;"]) ?>
        </div>
        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'pre_last_month', 'method' => 'GET',]) ?>
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="pre_last_month">

        <div class="form-group" style="float:left;margin-left: 5px;">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Позапрошлый <br> месяц', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'nn',]) ?>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?></div>
    <form method=post>
    <select name="list">
        <option value="vari-cream-com">vari-cream-com</option>
        <option value="joint-cream">joint-cream</option>
        <option value="gemor-cream">gemor-cream</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю ошибка в модели, вы вставили
 `$list = Yii::$app->request->post('list', 'mouse')` 
попробуйте без `mouse` 
`$list = Yii::$app->request->post('list')`

Comment: тогда вообще ошибку выдает, в `$list` почему-то ничего не попадает.

Comment: @cruim Тогда, видимо, проблема в том, что POST не отправляется, или отправляется не POST.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдаёт? думаю проблема с отправкой, хорошо бы увидеть код формы  полностью

Comment: @Arsen добавил код формы

Comment: @cruim а куда отправляет данные ваша форма? вы же просто вставили голую форму, в YII есть свои стандарты по работе с формами ( ActiveForm ) просто одним ответом вам не помочь,
почитайте документацию  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/form.view

Comment: может быть вы не туда поставили SELECT ? если в коде который вы показали должна быть одна форма вставьт SELECT до  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>